# Fixed Header and Footer hidden on input element JQuery Mobile 1.3.1 when using Desktop Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile (1.3.1) App which runs on desktop browsers (as well as tablets), mainly Chrome and FF.

The main page consists of a header, footer and multiple rows of input data (somewhat like a spreadsheet)

I have both the header and footer respectively defined as:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
```

However, as soon as I click in an input element either the header or footer or both are hidden, depending on how far down the page I have scrolled.

As soon as I click out of the input element, the header and/or footer returns.

I want the header and footer to stay put, as most of the time the cursor is in an input element on this page, but I can't find a way to achieve that.

Can anyone help?

Comment: hello.. can u make a fiddle for this?

Comment: or do you have a live example?

Comment: There is now a (rough) example page on http://eventingedge.com/mobile/demo/example.html [link](http://eventingedge.com/mobile/demo/example.html). HOWEVER, I just found that the problem only occurs when the browser is on my secondary Monitor and not my main monitor - that makes no sense. Problem occurs in Chrome and FF, but NOT IE10 or Safari.